# Time complexity with conditional statements

Tags: code-analysis

How does one calculate the time complexity with conditional statements that may or may not lead to higher oder results?

For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){  
   //an elementary operation   
   for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
       //another elementary operation  
       if (i == j){  
           for(int k = 0; k < n; k++){
               //yet another elementary operation
           }
       } else {
           //elementary operation
       }
   }
}
```

And what if the contents in the if-else condition were reversed?

Comment: As the snippet is C, C++, or Java-like, I've replaced the assignment operator with relational equality. Do roll back if it's not what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code takes O(n^2). First two loops take O(n^2) operations. The "k" loop takes O(n) operations and gets called n times. It gives O(n^2). The total complexity of your code will be O(n^2) + O(n^2) = O(n^2).

**Another try:**

```
 - First 'i' loop runs n times.
 - Second 'j' loop runs n times. For each of is and js (there are n^2 combinations):
     - if i == j make n combinations. There are n possibilities that i==j, 
      so this part of code runs O(n^2).
     - if it's not, it makes elementary operation. There are n^2 - n combinations like that
       so it will take O(n^2) time.
 - The above proves, that this code will take O(n) operations.
```

Comment: So conditional statements should be treated with the rule of sums?

Comment: There is no one rule for counting complexity. In your example it appears, that the 'k' loop is run once for each i. So it's run n times. n*n is n^2

Answer (score -1):

That depends on the kind of analysis you are performing. If you are analysing [worst-case complexity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worst-case_complexity), then take the worst complexity of both branches. If you're analysing [average-case complexity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average-case_complexity), you need to calculate the probability of entering one branch or another and multiply each complexity by the probability of taking that path.

If you change the branches, just switch the probability coefficients.

Comment: This algorithm is deterministic. It will always run same long.

Comment: Could you clarify on the worst case complexity? Taking  the worst complexity of both branches wont work for the given example because of the if-condition

Comment: The algorithm is deterministic, and that does not prevent for applying the same rules so you have "n loops" x "n loops" x "n loops every 1/n times" which has "n^2" complexity. If you switch the conditionals you have "n loops" x "n loops" x "n loops every (1 - n/n^2) times" which has "n^3" complexity.

Notice expectations are just the likeliness of something happening. It turns out when talking about deterministic algorithms, expectations are facts.