# The time complexity with conditional statements

Tags: algorithm

How does one calculate the time complexity with conditional statements

```
i=1
while i<=n
    j=1
    while i<=n
       if i==j
          k=1
          while k<=j
             k+=1
             print("hello")
       else
          print(""world)
       j*=2
   i*=2
```

The time complexity is θ(nlgn) or θ(lgn*lgn)?

Comment: Good to refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965609/time-complexity-with-conditional-statements

Comment: This algorithm does not end when *n* is greater than 0. Maybe it was intended to have `j<=n` as end-condition of the inner `while`?

Comment: Several of the tutorials on determining complexity deal with conditionals.  In short, you need to consider the average or worst-case condition (depending on which "complexity" you need) for each situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the second `while` loop should read `while j<=n`, the time complexity is:

*O(n)*

And the determining factor is exactly that loop on *k*.

We have:

```
i=1
while i<=n
    j=1
    while j<=n
        if i==j
            k=1
            while k<=j
                k+=1
                print("hello")
        else
            print("world")
        j*=2
    i*=2
```

The case `i==j` happens exactly once per iteration of the outer loop (where *i* changes), and could be made independent of the value of *j*, and taken out of the loop on *j*:

```
i=1
while i<=n
    j=1
    while j<=n
        if i!=j
            print("world")
        j*=2
    k=1
    while k<=i
        k+=1
        print("hello")
    i*=2
```

This changes the order of the `print` outputs, but that is irrelevant for determining the time complexity. We can even split that further:

```
i=1
while i<=n
    j=1
    while j<=n
        if i!=j
            print("world")
        j*=2
    i*=2

i=1
while i<=n
    k=1
    while k<=i
        print("hello")
        k+=1
    i*=2
```

So now for one iteration of the first outer loop, its inner while-loop iterates *logn* times. Each iteration of that inner loop takes constant time. In one case (when *i* equals *j*), there is a constant amount of time less work, so we have a time complexity of *O(logn)-O(1)* = *O(logn)* for this `while` loop.

That gives the first outer loop a time complexity of:

*O(logn) * O(logn) = O((logn)²)*

For one iteration of the second outer loop, its inner while-loop iterates *i* times, so we get a total number of iterations (when n is a power of 2) of *1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + n*, which is a [binary expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1990146/341715) -- equal to *2(2<sup>logn</sup>)-1 = 2n-1*, giving a time complexity of:

*O(2n-1) = O(n)*

For the overall time complexity, we take the sum, i.e.

*O((logn)²) + O(n) = O(n)*.

#### Illustration

To illustrate this time complexity, have a look at this implementation, where *n* is increased in each execution, and the units of work are counted and returned. The ratio between *n* and the amount of work approaches a constant:

```js
function work(n)  {
    var units = 0;
    var i=1
    while (i<=n) {
        var j=1
        while (j<=n) {
            if (i==j) {
                var k=1
                while (k<=j) {
                    k+=1
                    //print("hello")
                    units++;
                }
            } else {
                //print("world")
                units++;
            }
            j*=2
        }
        i*=2
    }
    return units;
}

// Demo
setTimeout(function loop(n=1) {
    var units = work(n);
    console.log(`n=${n}, work=${units}, ratio=${units/n}`);
    if (n < 100000000) setTimeout(loop.bind(null, n*2));
});
```

This is only an illustration, and does not count as proof.